# Oracle Triggers: How do I implement them?

Tags: oracle, plsql, foreign-keys, database-trigger

Working on school assignment, building databases. My database models a photography business. Most of it is simple but right now I'm stuck. So in my model, I have a Photography_Availability Entity (Ph_Av) and whenever a Photographer is scheduled or unavailable, there will be a corresponding entry with the date and time interval the Photographer is unavailable (Available_Date,Start_Time_Available,Fin_Time_Available). All of these are DateTime datatypes within my Oracle modeler. I want to implement a trigger that will check whenever someone attempts to schedule a photographer, if they are available or not (during the appropriate date and time interval). Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SAFE_SCHEDULE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PH_AV 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    ID VARCHAR(20) := NULL;
    AV_DATE DATE := NULL;
    START_TIME DATE := NULL;
    FIN_TIME DATE := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT PHOTOGRAPHER_ID INTO ID FROM PH_AV WHERE PHOTOGRAPHER_ID = :NEW.PHOTOGRAPHER_ID ;

    SELECT AVAILABILITY_DATE INTO AV_DATE FROM PH_AV WHERE PHOTOGRAPHER_ID = :NEW.PHOTOGRAPHER_ID;

    SELECT START_TIME_AVAIL INTO START_TIME FROM PH_AV WHERE PHOTOGRAPHER_ID = :NEW.PHOTOGRAPHER_ID;

    SELECT FIN_TIME_AVAIL INTO FIN_TIME FROM PH_AV WHERE PHOTOGRAPHER_ID = :NEW.PHOTOGRAPHER_ID;

    IF ((:NEW.START_TIME_AVAIL >= START_TIME AND :NEW.START_TIME_AVAIL <= FIN_TIME)
    OR (:NEW.FIN_TIME_AVAIL >= START_TIME AND :NEW.FIN_TIME_AVAIL <= FIN_TIME)
    OR (:NEW.START_TIME_AVAIL <= START_TIME AND :NEW.FIN_TIME_AVAIL >= FIN_TIME))
        THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot be scheduled, photographer unavailable');
    ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PHOTOGRAPHER SUCCESSFULLY SCHEDULED');
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA FOUND');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR-' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

The basic logic I want is that, say a Photographer has already been scheduled between 3 and 5pm and someone attempts to schedule that same Photographer between 2 and 4pm, clearly this collides. My if statement checks to see if the new inserted values collide with any possible scheduled values. Right now, after I run this, the Script Output does not state that there are any errors. But my message log claims quite a few (most of them being "null at (Internal error) No Throwable Stack Element").

This is my first time implementing a trigger, I think maybe its the Date datatype of my declared variables, but I'm at a loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited your title: SQL is not spelled "sequel", but more importantly, triggers have little to do with SQL\*Plus. The question is about Oracle triggers.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need 4 selects to read four different columns from the same table. In your case you don't even need any select at all. Just use the values from the `:new` record directly - they already contain the information you want (most obvious: with `SELECT PHOTOGRAPHER_ID ... WHERE PHOTOGRAPHER_ID = :NEW.PHOTOGRAPHER_ID`)

Comment: I suggesting add a 'describe PH_AV' to see the column types and perhaps a log of your error output will help show what you're seeing.

Comment: You should review your data model. First `DATE` data type always contain date and time value, there is not need to separate them (i.e  `AVAILABILITY_DATE`, `START_TIME_AVAIL`, `FIN_TIME_AVAIL`) - it will just create trouble. How do you handle the situation when a photographer is scheduled several times (e.g. from 3 to 4pm and 4:30 to 5pm). It will be difficult to handle this with one availability slot from 3 to 5pm

Answer (score 1):

With a simple structure `AVAIL` as follows and requirements to prevent overlap in entries, I would do something like the following:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE avail_sq;

CREATE TABLE avail
(
   avail_id  INTEGER,
   person_id INTEGER,
   start_dtm DATE,
   end_dtm DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_avail_trg
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON avail
COMPOUND TRIGGER
   TYPE avail_tt IS TABLE OF avail%ROWTYPE;

   avail_t avail_tt := avail_tt();
   l_cnt   INTEGER;

   BEFORE EACH ROW IS
   BEGIN
      avail_t.EXTEND;
      avail_t(avail_t.COUNT).avail_id := :new.avail_id;
      avail_t(avail_t.COUNT).person_id := :new.person_id;
      avail_t(avail_t.COUNT).start_dtm := :new.start_dtm;
      avail_t(avail_t.COUNT).end_dtm := :new.end_dtm;
   END BEFORE EACH ROW;

   AFTER STATEMENT IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN avail_t.FIRST..avail_t.LAST LOOP
         SELECT COUNT(*)
           INTO l_cnt
           FROM avail a
          WHERE a.person_id = avail_t(i).person_id
            AND ((a.start_dtm <= avail_t(i).start_dtm AND a.end_dtm > avail_t(i).start_dtm) OR
                 (a.start_dtm > avail_t(i).start_dtm AND a.start_dtm < avail_t(i).end_dtm))
            AND a.avail_id != avail_t(i).avail_id; -- Can't overlap itself

         IF l_cnt > 0 THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Overlap detected');
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

Instead of retrieving data from the table, I am doing more of an existence check. The two date/time filters checks for entries that overlap at any point. The first checks for existing entries with a start before or at the same time as your new row and end after the the start of the new row. The second checks for existing entries which start after your new row and also start before your new row ends.

Because you also allow updates on these fields, you need to use a `COMPOUND TRIGGER`, which allows you to gather the data you'll need for each row, but also process them after the statement has completed and mutation is done.

Comment: This won't work for UPDATEs though, will it? Since selecting from the table that you're updating will cause a "mutating" error.

Comment: You are corrent @kfinity, I missed the requirement for `UPDATE` when I read the original question. Updated with a `COMPOUND TRIGGER` to address that concern.

Comment: Yeah I've just ran into the mutation problem. Basically, I can't use triggers to alter a table I'm reading from. But I like your idea, even though I don't understand most of it (first semester interacting with oracle). I'm thinking that this is something I'm going to have to handle with constraints. I'll post a solution if i find one

Comment: Use a pragma autonomous transaction to counter the mutating problem